# Rewrite a SQL query to work on heroku

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

How would i rewrite this rails query to run on Heroku (Portegres)

```
@students = Student.find(:all, 
                  :conditions =>["(concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE ?) OR
                                  (concat(first_name, ' ', middle_names, ' ', last_name) LIKE ?)",
                                 "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%"]
                        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no point in using `concat()`. @Frank's answer is close, but the logic is broken.

`where (first_name || last_name LIKE ?)` evaluates to

"where `first_name` evaluates to `true` **or** where `last_name` contains search term"

This should get you the expected result

```
Student.all(
  :conditions => ["
    first_name like :search ||
    last_name like :search  ||
    middle_names like :search
    ",
    {:search => "%#{params[:search]}%"}
  ]
)
```

This will match all rows on `students` table that have `params[:search]` in any part of their name.

Comment: What, however if the query string contains, for example their first & last names. In this case my mySQL code would find them, however yours would fail.

Answer (score 5):

Ran in to this problem too. Postgres is case-sensitive with the LIKE operator, so here's what I did in a project. Also, I don't like to run postgres locally, so I have it run with LIKE in development (mysql/sqlite) and ILIKE in production (postgres). ILIKE is "case insensitive like"

/config/environment.rb

```
  DATABASE_OPERATOR = {
    :like_operator => "LIKE"
  }
```

/config/environments/production.rb

```
  DATABASE_OPERATOR = {
    :like_operator => 'ILIKE' #postgres awfulness
  }
```

Query

```
@students = Student.find(:all, :conditions => ['(concat(first_name, " ", last_name) #{DATABASE_OPERATOR[:like_operator]} ?) OR (concat(first_name, " ", middle_names, " ", last_name) #{DATABASE_OPERATOR[:like_operator]} ?)', "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%"])
```

Comment: How is this "postgres awfulness"? It's just different.

Comment: Hey, I can have an opinion. And it's this: if most other DBs have case insensitive searches for 'like', then go with that. And if you really want case-sensitive, let me search for that with a special command.

Comment: While this doesn't really help with my question, it's good to know. I'll be using ILIKE

Answer (score 1):

Use pipes || instead of CONCAT, that's standard SQL:

```
@students = Student.find(:all, :conditions => ['(first_name || last_name LIKE ?) OR (first_name || middle_names || last_name LIKE ?)', "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%"])
```

Check your quotes as well, you need single quotes ' for strings, double quotes " for database objects. MySQL accepts both, depending on the configuration, other databases only accept the standard.

Comment: `(first_name || last_name LIKE ?)` will only return rows where `%search%` exists in `last_name`.

Comment: According to some forum posts the behaviour of || in mySQL is non-standard and in pg it is concat.

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
Student.find(:all, 
                  :conditions =>["(concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE :text) OR
                                  (concat(first_name, ' ', middle_names, ' ', last_name) LIKE :text)",
                                 {:text=>"%#{params[:search]}%"]
                        )
```

Comment: What have you actually chaged?